# Splitting geolocation to longitude and latitude on XML IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml

Im splitting geolocations dynamically from a database eg 38.7890109,0.16608129999997345 to longitude and latitude on a XML feed, my code works fine when the geolocations are inputted correctly, but when it comes across data which has been loaded incorrectly by a client into the db, there is a IndexOutOfRangeException.

When I comment out the longitude = values[1]; code the feed loads up without the IndexOutOfRangeException so leaves me to believe that when it is splitting the geolocation on geoLoc.Split(',') the data it must be loading is dirty not able to split the geolocation causing the issue, I have attached the code below, any help is much appreciated.

```
string geoLoc = prop.AdministrativeFields.AddressFields.Geolocation;
string latitude = "";
string longitude = "";
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(geoLoc) && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(geoLoc))
{
XmlElement lat = doc.CreateElement(String.Empty, "latitude", String.Empty);
XmlElement lon = doc.CreateElement(String.Empty, "longitude", String.Empty);
string[] values = geoLoc.Split(',');
latitude = values[0];
longitude = values[1];
if (latitude.Length > 0 && longitude.Length > 0)
{
    XmlText lati = doc.CreateTextNode(latitude);
    XmlText longi = doc.CreateTextNode(longitude);
    lat.AppendChild(lati);
    lon.AppendChild(longi);
    XmlElement coords = doc.CreateElement(String.Empty, "coordinates", String.Empty);
    address.AppendChild(coords);
    coords.AppendChild(lat);
    coords.AppendChild(lon);
}
}
```

Comment: What is the exact value of `geoLoc`. Check that value and you can see what the problem is.

Comment: See posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48595116/c-sharp-not-able-to-find-a-node-within-the-xmlnode/48596215#48596215

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the `string[] values = geoLoc.Split(',');` part before accessing the array elements `latitude = values[0];` and `longitude = values[1];`.

Use:

```
if (values != null && values.Length >= 2)
{
    latitude = values[0];
    longitude = values[1];
    ...
}
```

If this check fails you should reload the data